# Add observation based on certain criteria in R

Tags: r

I would like to add observation based on certain criteria.

For example:

```
SN     Species       Habitat        X_Cor   Y_cor     Total 
1      monkey        grassland      4444    6666      6
2      porcupine     agri_Land      6666    5555      20
```

I would like to add observation up to 60 times. In above, the first observation is to be repeated 54 times (60-5), with value in "Total" 0. The second observation is to be repeated 40 times (60-20).

Furthermore,

I want to repeate first observation six times (because there is 6 in "Total").

I have 590 such observation. I would like to know how to code it in R.

Comment: Your question is rather cryptic, could you show some of what you've done so we can tease out the problem?

Comment: Upvoted the answer but downvoted the question because no response after 3 hours.

Answer (score 1):

If the criteria is to replicate the rows based on the values in 'Total', use `rep` to replicate the sequence of rows.

```
df1[rep(1:nrow(df1), df1$Total),]
```

or if we need a wrapper

```
library(splitstackshape)
expandRows(df1, "Total")
```

---

The part of the description `add observation upto 60 times. In above, the first observation is to be repeated 54 times (60-5)` is not clear from the example showed.  If we need to replicate based on the description

```
df1[rep(1:nrow(df1), c(54, 40)),]
```